# set initdb encoding for postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-initdb, pg-ctl

When I try to call pg_ctl with init[db] the option for setting the encoding is not recognized:

```
pg_ctl init -D=D:\testdata -E=UTF8 -U=postgres
pg_ctl: illegal option -- E
```

Has this changed? I used latest PostgreSQL 9.6 (zip download, x64).
When I don't use the -E switch everything works but the database cluster is initialized with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pg_ctl` does not have an option `-E`. If you want to run `initdb` through `pg_ctl`, you need to pass the `initdb` options using `-o` e.g. `pg_ctl initdb -D ... -o "-E=UTF8"`

But it's a lot easier to call `initdb` directly:

```
initdb -D=D:\testdata -E=UTF8 -U=postgres
```